# How do I create a scale bar using html and css

Tags: html, css, styles

I am practising creating websites and I have found a template which I am working on right now.There is a fancy scale bar on the page.Anyone can help me??I do not know how to create this,it looks hard to create.I have tried several times and I failed.

[The image of scale bar is right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvCyY.jpg)

Comment: `<input type="range" />` done.

Comment: _"I've tried several times and I failed"_ - Part of the deal is showing what you tried. Please post your attempts so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The `<meter></meter>` tag should be okay for this, though you'll need to style it to get the effect you want. [This](https://css-tricks.com/html5-meter-element/) site can give you pointers on that.